# Для оптимизации что лучше?

Tags: php, benchmark

Здравствуйте, хотел спросить совет есть ли разница использовать if в echo таким образом

```
echo 'text'.($a==$b?'yes':'no').'text';
```

или так лучше  для оптимизации

```
  echo 'text';
     if($a == $b)
     echo 'Yes';
 else
    echo 'no';
    echo 'text';
```

Comment: синтаксический сахар. пишите так, как удобней потом прочитать.

Comment: удобние первый вариант, но как вообще лучше?

Comment: читабельнее 2й вариант. И вообще странно, что Вас именно в этом месте беспокоит оптимизация. Уверен на 99% что у Вас кроме этого есть что оптимизировать. Не отвлекайтесь на ерунду)

Comment: Читабельнее скорее всего первый вариант. Второй слишком размазан. Я лично хоть и сам убедился в неоптимальности первого подхода буду продолжать пользоваться им.

Comment: Не то вы "оптимизирете", ой не то...

в прочем продолжайте "оптимизацию" пока будет работать.

Comment: Пишите так, как вам больше нравится.

Comment: Чисто по секрету:

    echo 'text', $a==$b?'yes':'no', 'text'; // и нет конкатенации :)

Чорт, не увидел камент @FLK. В общем, поддерживаю его)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

пользуйтесь как вам удобно, в разных ситуациях удобней использовать разные конструкции.

**upd:**

короткую запись удобно использовать когда необходимо присвоить переменной некоторое значение, например:

```
$a=$b?$c:$d;
//в противовес
if($b){
$a=$c;
}else{
$a=$d;
}
```

также удобно использовать при выводе:

```
echo $a?'hello':'world','taram-pam-pam',$b?'how':$c?'are':'you';
//противовес даже лень писать, думаю он очевиден
```

ну а полная запись, это когда надо выполнить несколько действий в блоке, в этой ситуации она бесспорный лидер.

**P.S.** тем не менее не стоит слишком запутывать код сокращенными конструкциями, всё таки он должен быть читаемым.

Comment: Результаты моего вчерашнего теста оказались неверны. Добавление прогревочного цикла перед самим тестом сделало результаты примерно одинаковыми. Видимо жесткий диск при нагрузке увеличивает обороты.  
6.7 и 5.6 секунд получилось вместо 12 и 5.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о целом, связанном предложении, то я бы предложил такой вариант:

```
function yesno($bool) { return $bool ? "yes" : "no"; }

printf("text: %s, text", yesno($a == $b));
```

Это оптимизация *читаемости и поддерживаемости*. Она, как правило, стоит *намного* больше, чем экономия на наносекундах скорости — потому что человеческое время стоит дороже машинного. А если что-то будет работать ощутимо медленно — профайлер покажет где узкое место, где стоит пересмотреть алгоритмы работы.

Comment: угу, давайте теперь для каждого условия, будем писать функции, которые к тому же дают дополнительную нагрузку на сервер, и исполняются медленней.

Comment: Померил на стареньком Xeon 2.8GHz. Скорость падает аж в 2 раза, но это значения не имеет, потому что речь идет о 494033.0 и 255897.67 итерациях в секунду. Если речь, например, о логах, а не дампе гигабайтной базы — кто вам с такой силой сервер мучает? А если о дампе базы — зачем для этого PHP?

Comment: полностью с вами согласен, мне тоже радует глаз конструкция типа:

     function poraidtivshkoluuzevremyapokushat($bool){return $bool?'пора идти в школу':'уже время покушать'}
     printf("А сейчас %s",poraidtivshkoluuzevremyapokushat($time>8));

Comment: Если Вы не осознаете разницу между Вашим и моим примером, то говорить тут, пожалуй, не о чем. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: @drdaeman прошу прощения, если случайно обидел своим примером (хотя он действительно радует мой глаз), я ошибочно принял ваш ответ и комментарий за сарказм.

Comment: @FLK: И я прошу у Вас прощения за резкость и что Вас запутал. Я, честно, не хотел — никакого сарказма не подразумевалось.